# how to use data-i18n on javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, alert, translate, i18next

I am using `i18next-1.6.3.min.js` for text translation in my program. I have been using the `data-i18n` as `<span data-i18n="Usr">User</span>`

which would translate the word User for me in whatever language I choose.

But when it comes to alerts for eg: `alert('Error..!');`  I wonder how can I use `i18next.js` on alerts as alerts don't come in `divs` or `spans`.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: You should provide some code of what you've done so far so we can help you

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, always remember to Google first. When I search for `i18next javascript alert` the first hit is a Stack Overflow question from 2014 answering your question.

Comment: @Pekka I googled it and I got the link. But still I didn't understood it completely thats why i reposted the same question again in a hope to get detailed information

Comment: Well, can you clarify what exactly you did not understand? It seems to be as easy as `alert(t("Usr"));`

Comment: i18n.init(function(t) {
    // translate nav
    $(".nav").i18n();
    // programatical access
    var appName = t("app.name");
});              @Pekka  the above code i found from the original post. So like how the author has written over here i.e var appname=t("app.name"); do i have to write for each text to be displayed in alert the same way. Cud U plz tel me wht is aap.name over here in the braces and also plz tell me with a piece of code if possible how to write for eg; I want "Task complete"  in alert using i18n js. using above code then how to write such code. Please guide me.

Comment: Do you have the translations already prepared? This may help: http://i18next.com/translate/